# what does "exec 5>>foobar.txt" do?

Tags: bash, sh, posix

What does the shell command

```
exec 5>>foobar.txt
```

do?  I can't google it for obvious reasons, and otherwise not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Why was this question down voted? I found it quite useful.

Comment: @MJWalsh gave it an upvote as I find it useful as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, it opens a file descriptor to append to the named file.

You would use this file descriptor like this:

```
echo "hello world" >&5
date >&5
while read line; do some_transformation; done < input_file >&5
```

Answer (score 3):

The command in question redirects file descriptor `5` to a file `foobar.txt`.

As for "where to start looking" - [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18904/133107) is a very good starting point.

Comment: To be more precise, a new shell is created to replace the current shell, but with any writes to file descriptor `5` appended to a file named `foobar.txt` in the current directory. Any program waiting for completion of the shell will wait for the new shell and receive its eventual exit status.